# ASP.Net MVC - Many to Many CRUD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, crud

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC and I'm having a few problems with Many to Many CRUD.
I need to create a N:N between two tables and create an entry before the two types are created.

I have the following code:

```
[Table("DadosOperacao")]
public class Operacao : IIdentificado
{
    Properties Here...

    /* Foreign Key Operacao */
    public virtual ICollection<OperacaoParte> ParteGroup { get; set; }
}

[Table("DadosParte")]
public class Parte : Pessoa
{
    Properties Here...

    /* Foreign Key Operacao */
    public virtual ICollection<OperacaoParte> OperacaoGroup { get; set; }
}

[Table("OperacaoParte")]
public class OperacaoParte
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Operacao")]
    public int OperacaoID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Parte")]
    public int ParteID { get; set; }

    public virtual Operacao Operacao { get; set; }

    public virtual Parte Parte { get; set; }

    public int IDTipoParte { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
I mapped my field with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OperacaoParte>()
    .HasKey(um => um.OperacaoParteID)
    .ToTable("OperacaoParte");

modelBuilder.Entity<OperacaoParte>()
    .HasRequired(um => um.Parte).WithMany(g => g.OperacaoGroup)
    .HasForeignKey(um => um.OperacaoID);

modelBuilder.Entity<OperacaoParte>()
    .HasRequired(um => um.Operacao).WithMany(g => g.ParteGroup)
    .HasForeignKey(um => um.ParteID);
```

My Action in the Controller

```
[RequiresLogin]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ManytoMany(OperacaoParte Data)
{
    ActionResult Saida;

    AfortContext Banco = AfortContext.Conectar();

    var Operacao = Banco.Operacoes.Where(m => m.ID == 1)
        .SingleOrDefault();
    var Parte = Banco.Partes.Where(c => c.CPF == 43143336854.ToString())
        .SingleOrDefault();
    if (Operacao != null && Parte != null)
    {
        var OperacaoParte = new OperacaoParte
        {
            Operacao = Operacao,
            Parte = Parte,
            OperacaoID = Operacao.ID,
            ParteID = Parte.ID,
            IDTipoParte = Parte.IDTipoParte
        };
        Banco.OperacaoParte.Add(OperacaoParte);
        Banco.SaveChanges();
    }
    Saida = RedirectToAction("Index", "Operacao");
    return Saida;
}
```

But when I try to update the data, I receive the following error

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries.
See the inner exception for details.System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: 
An error occurred while updating the entries.See the inner exception for details.System.Data.SqlClient.
SqlException: 
Invalid column name 'OperacaoID'.
Invalid column name 'ParteID'.
Invalid column name 'IDTipoParte'.
Invalid column name 'OperacaoParteID'.
Invalid column name 'OperacaoParteID'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `ICollection<Parte> ParteGroup` and `ICollection<Operacao> OperacaoGroup` you should write `ICollection<OperacaoParte> ParteGroup` and `ICollection<OperacaoParte> OperacaoGroup` accordingly.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I updated my code with the changes you said, but i dont know what i'm doing wrong :/